Remove source jars from classpath in Java Gradle
Is there a way to remove all source jar files from classpath.
I have a Java 13 gradle project, When I run application or unittests in IntelliJ  classpath includes source jars for dependencies. This seems to be unwanted behavior and duplicating dependencies.
E.g classpath has both
commons-lang3-3.14.0.jar
commons-lang3-3.14.0.src.jar
not sure what is wrong with my grade build file. It should only include commons-lang3-3.14.0.jar and not commons-lang3-3.14.0.src.jar

What unwanted behaviour? The source files aren't going to be run if they're not compiled.

One use case I have with our application is we use this classpath to compile custom Java code (user supplied) on the fly at runtime. Now since source jars are in the classpath they are beings passed when compiling the code this was not the case when we used old build system. Now I get out-of-memory error but if I debug and remove source jar code gets compiled on runtime.
Not sure what I am missing here. Is there a way to exclude all source jars.

I think you are doing something unusual in your buildscript. In a simple Java project, only the compiled JAR is placed on the classpath, and I have tested with that library. Further, there is no commons-lang3-3.14.0.src.jar published; it is commons-lang3-3.14.0-sources.jar. See Maven Central

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
